# What is the proper way to dynamically create and call a stored procedure in Delphi using FireDac?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac, anydac

I am relatively new to FireDAC.  I want to be able to call a stored procedure "on the fly", dynamically.  So far I have the following:

```pascal
function TForm21.ExecuteStoredProc(aSPName: string; aParams: TADParams): Boolean;
var
  LSP: TADStoredProc;
  i: Integer;
begin
  LSP := TADStoredProc.Create(nil);
  try
    LSP.Connection := ADConnection1;
    LSP.StoredProcName := aSPName;
    LSP.Prepare;
    for i := 0 to aParams.Count - 1 do
    begin
      LSP.Params[i].Value := aParams[i].Value;
    end;
    LSP.ExecProc;
  finally
    LSP.Free;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

I call it with

```pascal
procedure TForm21.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LParams: TADParams;
begin
  LParams := TADParams.Create;
  LParams.Add.Value := 612;
  LParams.Add.Value := '2008';

  ExecuteStoredProc('HDMTEST.dbo.spARCHIVE_HISTORY_DATA', LParams);
end;
```

However, the stored procedure fails to execute. That is, the code runs fine, no error message is shown, but the stored procedure doesn't run.

Further info -- it runs fine if I drop a component and set up the params in code.

Anyone have any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Fails how? any error message?

Comment: Sorry, fails to do anything.  No error message.  The code just executes.   I'll update the question.

Comment: Try to use ParamByName and manually define all values for the parameters. Your code is fine, the problem should rely on parameters order.

Comment: I would expect, that LSP.Params[0] is '@RETURN_VALUE', which returns SP error code. So, your code rather should look like "LSP.Params[i+1].Value := aParams[i].Valie".

Comment: @MatheusFreitas -- The ParamByName thing worked. But I think it worked because I wasn't putting the '@' at the beginning of the params.  Dopey me.

Comment: @da-soft  -- Dmitry, you were right as well.  That's why the ParamByName worked. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, if someone wants to formulate an official answer, I'll select it.  Thanks again.

Comment: This one should be da-soft, I mean, no way I can know more than the creator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as this q has been left unanswered for a while, I thought I'd try to get the code working without using the clues from the comments and found it not quite as easy as I'd imagined.

I immediately got stuck with the SP params.  I found this

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/TFDQuery,_TFDStoredProc_and_TFDUpdateSQL_Questions

which says

```
"If you have difficulties with manual definition of parameters,
populate the Params collection automatically and check how the
parameters are defined. Then compare that to your code. "
```

but I couldn't find a way of "automatically" populating the Params.  I asked on the EMBA
FireDac newsgroup and the FD author, Dimitry Arefiev, kindly explained that 
you can do that by checking that the FetchOptions include fiMeta, and then clearing and setting the FDStoredProc's StoredProcName.

Using a StoredProc in the pubs demo database on my SqlServer defined as follows:

```
create procedure test(@ANumber int, @AName varchar(20))
as
begin
  select
   @ANumber * 2 as "Number",
   @AName + @AName as "Name"
end
```

I changed a couple of sections of the OP's code like this

```
[...]
  LSP.Params.Clear;
  LSP.StoredProcName := '';
  LSP.FetchOptions.Items := LSP.FetchOptions.Items + [fiMeta];
  LSP.StoredProcName := aSPName;
  LSP.Prepare;
  Assert(LSP.ParamCount > 0);

  for i := 0 to aParams.Count - 1 do
  begin
    LSP.Params.ParamByName(aParams[i].Name).Value := aParams[i].Value;
  end;
[...]

procedure TForm21.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LParams: TFDParams;
  Param : TFDParam;
begin
  LParams := TFDParams.Create;
  Param := LParams.Add;
  Param.Name := '@ANumber';
  Param.Value := 612;

  Param := LParams.Add;
  Param.Name := '@AName';
  Param.Value := '2008';

  ExecuteStoredProc('test', LParams);
end;
```

and it worked fine.

The OP mentions in the q he'd first had the problem that the SP failed to execute
but that he'd found that it worked if he "[dropped] a component and set up the params in code" so I thought I'd include here a console application where of course necessarily everything is done in code.  This wasn't difficult, but the time it took me to get the Uses clause right is my main reason for posting this as an answer, for future reference.  W/o the correct uses, you get errors complaining about various class factories being missing.

Console app (created and tested in XE6):

```
program ConsoleStoredProcProject3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, FireDac.DApt, FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.ASync,
  FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Comp.Client,
  FireDAC.Phys.MSSQL, VCL.ClipBrd;

procedure TestSP;
var
  Connection : TFDConnection;
  StoredProc : TFDStoredProc;
  Param : TFDParam;
begin
  Connection := TFDConnection.Create(Nil);
  Connection.DriverName := 'MSSQL';
  Connection.Params.Values['Server'] := // your server name'';
  Connection.Params.Values['Database'] := 'pubs';
  Connection.Params.Values['user_name'] := 'user';    // adjust to suit
  Connection.Params.Values['password'] := 'password'; // ditto
  Connection.LoginPrompt := False;
  Connection.Connected := True;

  StoredProc := TFDStoredProc.Create(Nil);
  StoredProc.Connection := Connection;
  StoredProc.FetchOptions.Items := StoredProc.FetchOptions.Items + [fiMeta];
  StoredProc.StoredProcName := 'test';
  StoredProc.Prepare;
  Param := StoredProc.Params.ParamByName('@ANumber');
  Param.Value := 333;
  Param := StoredProc.Params.ParamByName('@AName');
  Param.Value := 'A';

  StoredProc.Active := True;

  WriteLn(StoredProc.FieldByName('Number').AsInteger);
  WriteLn(StoredProc.FieldByName('Name').AsString);

  ReadLn;
end;

begin
  try
    TestSP;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Clipboard.AsText := E.Message;
  end;
end.
```