# How do I call a MS SQL Server System Stored Procedure with Firedac?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac

I am converting my application from using raw ADO calls to using FireDac.

Currently, I have the following line of code:

```
TQueryRunner.ExecuteQueryNoMsg('exec(''sp_who @@spid'')', iRA,rs,conn,True);
```

I need to be able to call that `sp_id @@spid` call in FireDac and return the result set.  I can't seem to do so despite a number of different approaches.  I've tried calling it with TFDStoredProc, but the parameter requires a value, and there really isn't a value for it.  I've tried a TFDQuery, but that won't work at all (and by "won't work" i mean I get an access viloation when I try....)

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: long shot.... does the answer to this older question of yours help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705866/what-is-the-proper-way-to-dynamically-create-and-call-a-stored-procedure-in-delp

Comment: @Tanner Hehe -- that was a question I asked as well.  ;-)

Comment: yeh i noticed, hence the _older question of yours_ part, guess it doesn't help lol. got yourself a niche there

Comment: Executing `sp_who @@spid` or `EXEC sp_who @@spid` from `TFDQuery` worked fine for me ([`example`](http://pastebin.com/0Fuq1u2r)).

Comment: Hmmm.  Thought that's the very thing I tried.  Weird.

Comment: FireDAC uses `:` to denote parameters.  So your syntax (in FireDAC) should be `exec sp_who :spid`